Change of variable in functional integral
I have the following functional multiple integral
$$\int \mathcal{D}f_1(x)\mathcal{D}f_2(x)  e^{-i\int_0^{x}f_1(t)f_2(t)dt}G[f_1(x),f_2(x)]$$
where $G$ is some functional of $f_1$, $f_2$. I would like to perform a change of variables $(f_1,f_2)$ to $(u_1,u_2)$ defined by
$$u_1(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + 2\int_0^x f_1(t)dt,$$
$$u_2(x) = b_1 + 2b_2x + 2\int_0^x f_2(t)dt.$$
How could I do that? I am not really familiar with such functional integration.

Not an expert, but I guess you'll need to compute a kind of functional Jacobian matrix, whose components may be operators, and its functional determinant in consequence.
